# Overriding the AWT Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I am building on a java profiling tool, the mechanism requires all Thread instances of the application to be replaced by the subclass "ProfilingThread" which overrides some of the threads's behavior to achieve the profiling functionality.

Given the Java application's source code, I can simply re-factor all "Thread" class to "ProfilingThread" class.  However, the AWT event dispatcher's thread is not instantiated by user's code, it is instead created autonomously when AWT functions are called.

What can I do to replace AWT event dispatcher's Thread instance with a ProfilingThread instance?

All ideas and criticisms are welcome.

Comment: Sorry about that, topic question added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a little criticism: Hacking the java internals in a production-grade application is usually not a good idea.

A better solution would be to add specialized handling for any instance of the event dispatching thread and only profile your own classes. It's also quite possible that other parts of java will start other threads that also don't extend off of your ProfilingThread...

But if you *have* to change the AWT event dispatching thread:

The event dispatching thread is a `java.awt.EventDispatchThread` instance in the system event queue, obtainable by

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue()
```

To replace the thread you have to reimplement the `java.awt.EventDispatchThread` using your `ProfilingThread` or better extend the `EventDispatchThread` and add your profiling functions.

Then you have to set the field using reflection as it is private and usually can't be changed from the outside. (There are plenty examples on how to do that)

As a reference: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/EventQueue-source.html

Comment: You are right, I am already regretting taking the approach of hacking java internals.